# How to convert the regular expression $\emptyset^*$ to an NFA?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

The question is to convert the following regular expression to an NFA: $\emptyset^*$.

I know that the symbol phi in Theory Of Computation means an empty set. But what does phi^* mean?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a phi symbol (phi is written either $\phi$ or $\varphi$, and the uppercase version is $\Phi$), but you are right that $\emptyset$ denotes the empty set.

The star symbol is known as the [Kleene Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) and $A^*$ is the set containing the empty word (denoted by $\varepsilon$) and all the words that can be obtained by concatenating any finite number of words from $A$. Formally, $A^0=\{\varepsilon\}$, $A^i=\{xy \mid x \in A^{i−1},y \in A\}$ for any integer $i>0$, and $$A^*=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A^i.$$

This should be all you need to solve the exercise.
As a hint: can you figure out what $\emptyset^i$ is when $i > 0$?